# Can lenses for DSLR bodies be mounted on SLT bodies?

Tags: lens, lens-mount, sony-alpha

Can I use a lens that normally should be used on a DSLR, but mount it on a SLT? If not, what is the difference between a DSLR lens and a SLT lens?

My camera is a Sony α68.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use lens brand X on interchangeable lens camera brand Y?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/62000/can-i-use-lens-brand-x-on-interchangeable-lens-camera-brand-y)

Comment: @PhilipKendall Disagreed on the dupe, *assuming* this question is primarily about compatibility of Sony α lenses on SLT bodies vs DSLR. However, if it's about *any* DSLR lens on the α68 body, then I would agree with you.

Comment: I think we need the OP to clarify that one :-)

Comment: Let us then ask: @Gabriel, do you mean a Sony A-mount dSLR lens on a dSLT? or a non-Sony dSLR lens to a Sony dSLT?

Comment: What @scottbb said - in almost all cases A-mount is A-mount BUT NOTE that in a **very few** cases there can be mechanical issues due to specialist lens design. This is more liable to occur with using newer lenses on older cameras with the same mount. In a VERY FEW cases a moving mirror may strike the rear lens element. I've heard of this happening with a few selected teleconverters which were targeted at specific lenses. Both lens and teleconverter are liable to be proced 10x+ above what you or I would ever consider buying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**. Sony A-mount lenses (and Minolta A-mount lenses) can be mounted on your camera.

From the standpoint of the lens operation (focusing motor, aperture, mount, etc.), there is no difference between a SLR with a mirror and a SLT with a [pellicle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pellicle_mirror) mirror. Lenses for your Sony Alpha 68 use the [A-mount](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minolta_A-mount_system) system, just like any other Sony interchangeable lens camera with a mirror.

It is possible in some cases to mount lenses from other manufacturers on the Sony A-mount bodies. This usually results in reduced functionality (usually loss of autofocus, and perhaps aperture control). Lenses for most camera systems with a larger [*flange focus distance*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flange_focal_distance) or *registration distance* than the A-mount (44.5mm) can be physically mounted on the Sony body by use of an appropriate adapter.

See also: [Can I use lens brand X on interchangeable lens camera brand Y?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/62000/can-i-use-lens-brand-x-on-interchangeable-lens-camera-brand-y)

Comment: Okay. So if i find a lens i want to buy and it says A-mount i can use it even if the website says its "specially made for Sony's dSLR cameras"? Ect. Sony SAL-55200 SAM

Comment: @Gabriel yes. Realize that SLTs are a subset of DSLRs; that is, SLTs *are* DSLRs (but non-pellicle mirror DSLRs are *not* SLTs). So, the Sony AF DT 55-200mm F4-5.6 (Sony product code SAL-55200 SAM) is compatible with your alpha 68.